# Tween max opacity in ie8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, opacity, gsap

I'm trying to use tween max and superscroll script, to handle opacity of my content while scrolling.

This works like a charm in chrome, safari, ff, ie9 and ie10.
However, I have an issue with ie8.

You can see the problem in this page : http://www.promenade-sainte-catherine.com/localisation

When scrolling down in ie8, the menu on the left changes its color to become white. This is okay, and once the animation is finished, it becomes green again.

This is my css :

```
   body #menuGaucheContainer #menuGauche .logoPSC {
    position: relative; zoom:1;}
    /* line 270, sass/partial/_global.scss */
    body #menuGaucheContainer #menuGauche .logoPSC #log1, body #menuGaucheContainer #menuGauche                .logoPSC #log2 {
      opacity: 0;
      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
      position: absolute;
      top: -109px;
      left: 75px; }
```

And this is the tweenmax call

```
   controller.addTween('#aucoeurducentrevilleContainer', 
        TweenMax.fromTo(jQuery('#img2Localisation'), 1,
            {css:{opacity:0}},
            {css:{opacity:1}}), 
        200);
    controller.addTween('#aucoeurducentrevilleContainer', 
        TweenMax.fromTo(jQuery('#log2'), 1,
            {css:{opacity:0}},
            {css:{opacity:1}}), 
        200);
```

If I remove the "filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);" line. Then it works good, but nothing have an opacity of zero at the beginning of the page.

If I add css:{opacity:X, alpha:X}, nothing changes,

If I change {css:{opacity:0}} to {css:{alpha:0}}, it kind of works, but I still have some issues.

Does anyone have any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're using a VERY old version of the GreenSock files (TweenMax). You should definitely update - that may fix the problem right there. http://www.greensock.com/?download=GSAP-JS Otherwise, I'd be curious if tweening to opacity:0.99 instead of 1 solves things for you.

Comment: Yep this totally made the trick : opacity:0.99 instead of 1. 

Thanks a lot. 

Is there a way that I accept your answer so that you can benefit the points (There's still a lot I don't understand in Stackoverflow)

Comment: Sure, I'll just add it as an answer that you can accept. I probably should have done that originally anyway - sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using a **VERY** old version of the GreenSock files (TweenMax). You should definitely update - that may fix the problem right there. http://www.greensock.com/?download=GSAP-JS Otherwise, try tweening to opacity:0.99 instead of 1 solves things for you. But again, I'm pretty sure that updating will help because if my memory serves correctly, this particular scenario had a workaround applied in a TweenMax update a while back.

Comment: I didn't wanted to update the file, fearing other problem that could come from that. So the solution of 0.99 instead of 1 worked perfectly :).Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I also had this issue with a new version of Greensock, and it's not because the plugin, but because of CSS. The error is in the beginning statement:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
opacity:    0;
```

While this is perfectly ok if you don't want to support IE7, it will break TweenMax's animation rules. The fix is to add the IE5-IE7 css rule, even if you won't support IE7 in general:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
opacity:    0;
```